# PHP getting a specific value out of an array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

I am currently using facebook php and am trying to get a specific page name based off of a user entered name.

For example lets say I have an array of (Apple,Orange,Pear). I have a variable $var = "Pea". How would i set a new variable lets say result = Pear. At the moment I am hardcoding in the exact facebook page name like so :

```
    if($key['name']=="Exact Page Name HERE"){
        $post = $fb->post('/' . $key['id'] . '/feed',$params, $key['access_token']);
        $post = $post->getGraphNode()->asArray();
        echo ("Post successful");
    }
```

My goal is to be able to get the array of user managed pages from facebook and then compare the name of each page to the user entered variable and set the page name = to the name that matches the variable the closest.

Comment: If you know how to get the array of names then all that is left is to use the FOREACH() command to go through the array to compare each name. Also, you should use the "===" command since "==" can match things you don't really way to match. (like Pear and Peach => Pea are the same).

Comment: @MarkManning thanks for the reply. I currently have a for each to obtain the full array. My question though is now with the foreach loop how do I compare the names to my variable? As in this case the facebook page name could be 'Ford Cars' but the user variable is 'Ford' so how do i match them?

Comment: Do you want to match only at the beginning or anywhere in the string? If `$var = "pple"` should it match `Apple`?

Comment: @Barmar If it is possible to match anywhere in the string I believe that it would be helpful. Again I wouldnt be using just letters such as 'pple' It would be 'Ford' so Id like it to match 'Ford Ireland'

Comment: That's at the beginning. Do you mean `Ireland` should match `Ford Ireland`?

Comment: As Barmar has said below. But - are we missing something? Do you want compare the VARIABLE or the contents of the variable? Those are two different things.  If your string is inside of a variable then you want the second. If the variable itself is the name - that is different. :-)

Comment: If you want to display the list of pages administered by the user any way, then why would you still need to match any partial input? Let them select the specific page from the list of pages directly, then you don’t need any more “guess work.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strpos()` to see if the substring `$var` is in an array element. It will return `0` if `$var` is found at the beginning of the string.

```
foreach ($array as $index => $el) {
    if (strpos($el, $var) === 0) {
        // match found, do what you want
    }
}
```

Make sure you use `===`, not `==`, because `strpos` returns `false` if the string is not found, and what you use loose comparison `false == 0`.

If you want to match anywhere in the string, use `strstr()`

```
if (strstr($el, $var)) {
    // match found, do what you want
}
```

Comment: I know of the strpos() function however how would i set that array value that matches the $var to =  a new variable?

Comment: When a match is found, set `$array[$index]` to what you want.